# Ускорить работу функции

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, group-by

Помогите оптимизировать код. Написал такую функцию:

```py
def vp(df):
    df_v=df.groupby('col1').sum().reset_index()
    df['target']=0
    for i in range(0, (len(df)-1)):
        for j in range (0, (len(df_v)-1)):
            
            if  df_v['col1'][j] == df['col1'][i]:
            
                df['target'][i]=df_v['vol'][j]
    return df
```

Проблема в том, что она работает медленно на больших наборах, как ее можно ускорить?
Пример входных данных: `dict= {'col1':[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1], 'vol':[10, 15, 10, 20, 10, 15, 10]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - вы можете воспользоваться [GroupBy.transform()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df["target"] = df.groupby("col1")["vol"].transform("sum")
```

результат:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
   col1  vol  target
0     1   10      40
1     2   15      15
2     3   10      20
3     1   20      40
4     3   10      20
5     5   15      15
6     1   10      40
```

PS на будущее - вопрос должен включать описание алгоритма, а не только код, который вы хотите исправить или улучшить. Также стоит приводить в вопросе желаемый результат.

Советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: у него в конце вроде `5     5   15       0
6     1   10       0`  если я правильно его запустил

Comment: @splash58, я подозреваю, что это результат ошибки в коде функции )

Comment: я честно говоря, не очень понял, что там делается - вы быстрее ответ написали :) поэтому даже не знаю

Comment: Всем спасибо. Вопрос решен. С хорошим тоном постановки вопроса ознакомился :) впредь учту. И да 0 который возвращал код - ошибка :(